# does left join order affect execute result and duration in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

view a has 1 million+ rows. table b has 50000+ rows.
when left join, `a left join b left join c` cost 1 minute.
b left  join a left join c cost 10 seconds.
they return same results.

does left join order  affect result and execute duration?

Comment: The second query only read all 50,000 rows in B, contrast with having to read all 1M  rows in A *THEN* filter out only matches rows. That's why second query is much faster than first one. http://vinaykumarchella.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/4.png

Comment: second query left join A, also read A

Comment: from my link, Step J2 has ON filter ie. it filter join condition hence, not all row is read. Whereas first query all rows from A is read

Answer (score 3):

They shouldn't return the same results, unless you have a `where` clause that does additional filtering.

The first should keep all 1,000,000 rows in A.  The second should keep all 50,000 rows in B.  If they match, then every row in A matches at least one row in B and every row in B matches at least one row in A.

As for your question, the join order does affect the results (as I just described).  It doesn't really affect the execution, because the optimizer determines the execution plan independently of how the joins are ordered in the `from` clause.  (Of course, different semantic differences will result in different execution plans.)